# I took Celpip General test in 2021. My scores are: Speaking 8, Reading 8, Listening 8, Writing 7. What is my overall CLB score?

Tags: canada, express-entry

I'm confused about CLB scores. As, neither IRCC nor Celpip official websites do not have any information regarding my question. I cannot understand either I have CLB 7 or CLB 8 ?

Comment: What programs are you applying/interested in? There is no "overall" score for CLB and it does not matter. Different programs have different requirements, which will specify what is the minimum is for each or all competencies (e.g. CEC), or consider each competency separately (e.g. for EE points).

Comment: @xngtng I am interested in Prince Edward Island's PNP program. When filling out the application, it asks you to provide your overall CLB lvl, which confuses me.

Comment: PEI uses the lowest score of each ability.

Answer (score 2):

For most federal immigration programs, the requirement is formulated as a minimum score required for each language ability (speaking, reading, listening writing).

For example, the Federal Skilled Worker Program requires CLB 7 as "minimum level for all four abilities". Thus, your score would satisfy this requirement if you are applying under FSWP stream.

Some programs do not require the same score for all abilities, as is the case for the Federal Skilled Trades Porgram. In that case, CLB 5 is required as the minimum level for speaking/listening, and CLB 4 for reading/writing.

For [CRS points](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/criteria-comprehensive-ranking-system/grid.html), each language ability obtains its own points on the grid. For your score (if you are unmarried and English is chosen as the first official language), you would get 23 points for each of speaking/reading/listening and 17 points for writing. That is, in total, 23 x 3 + 17 = 86 points would be awarded to you in the CRS based on your language test results.

> I cannot understand either I have CLB 7 or CLB 8 ?

So this does not really matter for immigration. You have to verify the score for each of the abilities against the requirement as it is formulated.

---

Provincial programs may have different formulations of the language requirements. You will have to check how the requirement is expressed for the programs you are interested in.

Note that indeed IRCC (federal government) cannot help you with questions with provincial programs (at least not until the federal stage), questions need to be directed to the provincial department responsible.

For PEI, the [instruction for Express Entry](https://www.princeedwardisland.ca/sites/default/files/publications/pei_pnp_express_entry_guide.pdf) says

> The lowest score achieved in the 4 skills (Reading, Writing,
> Speaking, Listening) is your score. For example if you have a 7 in Reading, Writing and Speaking but a 5
> in Listening your CLB will be 5.

So your score would be 7 as defined for PEI Express Entry programs.